# Pandas assign value based on next row(s)

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this simple pandas DataFrame with columns 'record', 'start', and 'param'. There can be multiple rows with the same record value, and each unique record value corresponds to the same start value. However, the 'param' value can be different for the same 'record' and 'start' combination:

```py
pd.DataFrame({'record':[1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,7,8], 'start':[0,5,7,13,13,19,27,38,38,38,54], 'param':['t','t','t','u','v','t','t','t','u','v','t']})
```

I'd like to make a column 'end' that takes the value of 'start' in the row with the next unique value of 'record'. The values of column 'end' should be:

```py
[5,7,13,19,19,27,38,54,54,54,NaN]
```

I'm able to do this using a for loop, but I know this is not preferred when using pandas:

```py
max_end = 100
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    try:
        n = 1
        next_row = df.iloc[idx+n]
        while next_row['start'] == row['start']:
            n = n+1
            next_row = df.iloc[idx+n]
        end = next_row['start']
    except:
        end = max_end
    df.at[idx, 'end'] = end
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this without a for loop?

Comment: I believe you had tried something, right? Please provide your try here and Can you please explain a little bit how that end column created(Conditions....)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no doubt there is a smarter solution but here is mine.

```
df1['end'] = df1.drop_duplicates(subset = ['record', 'start'])['start'].shift(-1).reindex(index = df1.index, method = 'ffill')
```

-=EDIT=-
Added subset into `drop_duplicates` to account for question amendment

Comment: This worked for the example I posted. I realized I should have provided a more detailed example of what I'm doing because it doesn't work when using my real DataFrame. I updated the question to reflect that!

Comment: Try now, should just be the case of only dropping duplicates amongst those columns

Answer (score 1):

This solution is equivalent to @Quixotic22 although more explicit.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
'record':[1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,7,8],
'start':[0,5,7,13,13,19,27,38,38,38,54],
'param':['t','t','t','u','v','t','t','t','u','v','t']
})
max_end = 100

df["end"] = None  # create new column with empty values
loc = df["record"].shift(1) != df["record"] # record where the next value is diff from previous

df.loc[loc, "end"] = df.loc[loc, "start"].shift(-1)  # assign desired values
df["end"].fillna(method = "ffill", inplace = True)  # fill remaining missing values
df.loc[df.index[-1], "end"] = max_end  # override last value

df
```